# SAP Crystal Report : Subreport not showing data in production

Tags: crystal-reports, report, subreport

I have a main report and 5 subreports, everything is working well except 1 subreport.

In development mode when I preview the main report all the subreports showing data perfectly, especially the subreport "Symptom/s" is fine:

[image: Development Preview]

But in production mode, the subreport "Symptom/s" is not coming:

[image: Production Preview]

```
 private void loadReport(Int64 appointmentID)
    {
        try
        {
            rd = new ReportDocument();
            //For main patient record
            SqlCommand cmd1 = new SqlCommand("st_getPatientBill", MainClass.con);
            cmd1.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@appID", appointmentID);
            SqlDataAdapter da1 = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd1);
            DataTable dt1 = new DataTable();
            da1.Fill(dt1);
            rd.Load(Application.StartupPath + "\\Reports\\PrescriptionReport.rpt");
            rd.SetDataSource(dt1);

            ConnectionInfo ci = new ConnectionInfo();
            ci.DatabaseName = "cms";
            ci.UserID = "sa";
            ci.Password = "12345";
            ci.ServerName = "DESKTOP-753VMJS";
            Tables tables = rd.Database.Tables;
          
            SqlCommand cmd4 = new SqlCommand("st_getInternalMedicine", MainClass.con);
            cmd4.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            cmd4.Parameters.AddWithValue("@appID", appointmentID);
            SqlDataAdapter da4 = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd4);
            DataTable dt4 = new DataTable();
            da4.Fill(dt4);

            rd.Subreports[0].SetDataSource(dt4);

            //For external medicine
            SqlCommand cmd3 = new SqlCommand("st_getExternalMedicine", MainClass.con);
            cmd3.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            cmd3.Parameters.AddWithValue("@appID", appointmentID);
            SqlDataAdapter da3 = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd3);
            DataTable dt3 = new DataTable();
            da3.Fill(dt3);

            rd.Subreports[0].SetDataSource(dt3);



            //For disease 
            SqlCommand cmd5 = new SqlCommand("st_getPatientDiseaseWRTAppointment", MainClass.con);
            cmd5.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            cmd5.Parameters.AddWithValue("@appID", appointmentID);
            SqlDataAdapter da5 = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd5);
            DataTable dt5 = new DataTable();
            da5.Fill(dt5);

            rd.Subreports[0].SetDataSource(dt5);


            //For symptoms 
            SqlCommand cmd6 = new SqlCommand("st_getPatientSymptomsWRTAppointment", MainClass.con);
            cmd6.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            cmd6.Parameters.AddWithValue("@appID", appointmentID);
            SqlDataAdapter da6 = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd6);
            DataTable dt6 = new DataTable();
            da6.Fill(dt6);

            rd.Subreports[0].SetDataSource(dt6);

            //For tests 
            SqlCommand cmd7 = new SqlCommand("st_getPatientTestWRTAppointment", MainClass.con);
            cmd7.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            cmd7.Parameters.AddWithValue("@appID", appointmentID);
            SqlDataAdapter da7 = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd7);
            DataTable dt7 = new DataTable();
            da7.Fill(dt7);

            rd.Subreports[0].SetDataSource(dt7);

            //For internal medicine
            foreach (CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.Table table in tables)
            {
                TableLogOnInfo tableLogonInfo = table.LogOnInfo;
                tableLogonInfo.ConnectionInfo = ci;
                table.ApplyLogOnInfo(tableLogonInfo);
            }
            crystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = rd;
            crystalReportViewer1.RefreshReport();

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            if (rd != null)
            {
                rd.Close();
            }
        }
    }
```

The details are above

Answer (score 0):

I can recommend checking the following:
a) try to find all tables, objects in the report which don't work
(specially try to connect the subreport to different development server in design time it will unveil you hidden dependency of objects in the subreport

b) don't forget to reimport the subreport after you finished any updates :)

b)  try to connect all table objects by the following procedure:
(apply it on main report (_reportDocument)

CrystalDecisions.Shared.TableLogOnInfo tableLogOnInfo = new CrystalDecisions.Shared.TableLogOnInfo();

```
        tableLogOnInfo.ConnectionInfo.ServerName = this.DbServer;
        tableLogOnInfo.ConnectionInfo.DatabaseName = this.DbCatalog;
        tableLogOnInfo.ConnectionInfo.Password = this.DbPassword;
        tableLogOnInfo.ConnectionInfo.UserID = this.DbUser;
        tableLogOnInfo.ConnectionInfo.IntegratedSecurity = this.DbIntegratedSecurity;

        foreach (Table tbl in _reportDocument.Database.Tables)
        {
            tbl.ApplyLogOnInfo(tableLogOnInfo);
        }

        foreach (Section sec in _reportDocument.ReportDefinition.Sections)
        {
            foreach (ReportObject obj in sec.ReportObjects)
            {
                if (obj.Kind == CrystalDecisions.Shared.ReportObjectKind.SubreportObject)
                {
                    string subDocName = ((SubreportObject)obj).SubreportName;
                    ReportDocument subDoc = ((SubreportObject)obj).OpenSubreport(subDocName);
                    foreach (Table tbl in subDoc.Database.Tables)
                    {
                        tbl.ApplyLogOnInfo(tableLogOnInfo);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

P.